# read() not blocking as expected

Tags: c++, bash, pipe

I have a thread in a C++ program dedicated to reading from a named pipe that is written to via a bash script waiting for user input. I want ReadFromPipe() to be blocking and react to user input every time it's sent through the pipe.

read() isn't blocking for me in this code snippet, and I'm unsure why.

Bash:

```
# create pipe
write_pipe=/tmp/bash_to_c

if [[ ! -p $write_pipe ]]; then
    mkfifo $write_pipe
fi

USER_INPUT=""

while true; do
    read USER_INPUT
    echo $USER_INPUT > $write_pipe
done
```

C++:

```
std::string ReadFromPipe()
{
    char buffer[500];
    int fd; 
    std::string pipe = "./tmp/bash_to_c";

    fd = open(pipe.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, buffer, 500);
    
    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;
    buffer[strlen(buffer)] = '\0';
    
    close(fd);

    return std::string(buffer);
}

void* pipeCommunicationThreadFunc(void *args)
    {
        bool continueReadingFromPipe = true;
        while(continueReadingFromPipe)
        {
            // read from pipe
            std::string message = ReadFromPipe();
            std::cout << "message: " << message << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it printing anything?

Comment: By "not blocking" do you mean it never waits and returns an empty string? Or does it wait then return a partial string?

Comment: it prints "message: " over and over and over again

Comment: I mean that it never waits and returns and empty string repeatedly.

Comment: You aren't checking if opening the pipe actually succeeds - and the filename `"./tmp/bash_to_c"` looks wrong. You create `"/tmp/bash_to_c"` not `"./tmp/bash_to_c"` so unless you start the program from `/` it _will_ fail. Do `cd /` and then type the path to the C++ program to run it. It could work then.

Comment: If the string it reads doesn't have a newline, all sorts of bad things will happen... You need to use `read()`'s return value instead of ignoring it. Easier to just use a `std::ifstream` to read it so you don't have to implement your own line-based buffering.

Comment: `buffer[strlen(buffer)] = '\0';` is an anti-pattern. `strlen` searches for a pre-existing NUL terminator, so if there's none this statement will not add one, but cause undefined behavior. Remove this line, it's pointless. Ensure there's a NUL in some other way. Even better, switch to C++ strings, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't check if opening the pipe actually succeeds and it looks like you actually try to open the wrong file. Also, the `ReadFromPipe` function can be replaced with `std::getline` if you use the standard `std::ifstream` to open the pipe.

Alternative version:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

// made atomic and reachable from outside the function
std::atomic<bool> continueReadingFromPipe = true;

// Make it "void" if you use std::thread, "void*" if you use the C interface pthread
void pipeCommunicationThreadFunc() {
    std::string pipe = "/tmp/bash_to_c"; // corrected path
    std::string message;

    do {
        std::ifstream ps(pipe); // use std::ifstream() instead of open()

        if(ps) {  // checks that it's opened/in a good state
            while(continueReadingFromPipe) {  // continue reading while reading succeeds
                if(std::getline(ps, message)) // read a line from pipe
                    std::cout << "message: " << message << std::endl;
                else
                    break; // failed reading, break out
            }
        } else { // failed opening the pipe, abort
            continueReadingFromPipe = false;
        }
    } while(continueReadingFromPipe);  // loop and reopen the pipe
}
```